# Convergence of inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, inverse

Suppose that $A,A_1,A_2,\ldots\in\mathbb R^{p\times p}$ are invertible square matrices such that $\|A-A_n\|=o(a_n)$ as $n\to\infty$, where $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

> Is it true that $\|A^{-1}-A_n^{-1}\|=o(a_n)$ as $n\to\infty$ as well?

Here is my attempt. We have that
\begin{align*}
A^{-1}-A_n^{-1}
&=A^{-1}(A_n-A)A_n^{-1}\\
&=A^{-1}(A_n-A)A_n^{-1}AA^{-1}\\
&=A^{-1}(A_n-A)(I-A^{-1}[A-A_n])^{-1}A^{-1}.
\end{align*}
Using the properties of the Frobenius norm (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1393667/23249)), we obtain
\begin{align*}
\|A^{-1}-A_n^{-1}\|
&\le\|A^{-1}\|^2\|A_n-A\|\|(I-A^{-1}[A-A_n])^{-1}\|.
\end{align*}
Since $\|A^{-1}[A-A_n]\|<1$ for sufficiently large values of $n$, we have that
$$
\|(I-A^{-1}[A-A_n])^{-1}\|
\le\sum_{k\ge0}\|(A^{-1}[A-A_n])^k\|
\le\sum_{k\ge0}(\|A^{-1}\|\|A-A_n\|)^k<\infty
$$
for sufficiently large values of $n$. We conclude that $\|A^{-1}-A_n^{-1}\|=o(a_n)$ as $n\to\infty$.

> Is this correct? Is there a simpler way to show this? The only not straightforward part of the proof is to show that $\|A_n^{-1}\|$ is bounded. Is there an easy to way to see that $\|A_n^{-1}\|$ is bounded?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $B \to B^{-1}$ is continuous on the invertible $n \times n$ matrices, using the formula $B^{-1} = \text{adj}(B)/\det(B)$, where $\text{adj}(B)$ is the adjugate of $B$.
Since $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \cup \{A\}$ is a compact set of invertible matrices, 
so is $\{A_n^{-1}\}_{n=1}^\infty \cup \{A^{-1}\}$.  Therefore it is bounded.