# How to establish the identity $\Vert A B \Vert_F \leq \Vert A \Vert_F \Vert B \Vert_F$ for the Frobenius matrix norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

The Frobenius matrix norm is defined for $m \times n$ real matrices as
$$
\Vert A \Vert_F = + \sqrt{\mbox{Trace}(A^T A)} \tag{1}
$$

For  matrices $A$ and $B$ of sizes $(m \times n)$ and $(n \times k)$ respectively, the product $A B$ is well-defined.

In some text-books, I have seen the following identity (without proof):
$$
\Vert A B \Vert_F \leq \Vert A \Vert_F \Vert B \Vert_F \tag{2}
$$

The identity (2) is very useful in calculations in Numerical Linear Algebra.

I like to know how this can be proved.

Does the proof involve some properties in Matrix Algebra involving the trace operator?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393301/frobenius-norm-of-product-of-matrix

Comment: Thanks - I just saw it.. A nice application of Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality!