# $\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} A^l $ for sub stochastic matrix

Tags: markov-chains

Let $A$ be a sub stochastic matrix (sum of rows  is less or equal to 1) and also we know that the sum of at least one row is strictly less than 1.

Ho do I show that $$ \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} A^l = (I - A)^{-1} $$

I think I can do it if  all eigenvalues of $A$ are less than 1 and $A$ is diagonalizable but not sure how to show it in general.

Comment: Show that the sum on the left converges. Then multiply it by $(I-A)$.

Comment: It converges if the eigenvalues of A are less than 1 but how do I show that ?

Comment: What is the matrix norm of such matrix ?

Comment: Less or equal to  1 I guess but then the largest eigenvalue can be 1 and we don't have  converges.

Comment: The answer to that may be of help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393301/frobenius-norm-of-product-of-matrix