# Frobenius norm of sums of matrix products

Tags: matrices, summation, normed-spaces

If we have a sum of products of two conformable matrices: $\sum_{i=1}^NA_i'B_i$, I would like to understand if the following is generally true:

$$
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^NA_i'B_i \right\|\leq \max_{1\leq i\leq N} \left\| A_i\right\|\left\|\sum_{i=1}^NB_i \right\|
$$

I do not require that $A_i$ or $B_i$ (or both) are positive definite for all $i$.

Comment: see first answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393301/frobenius-norm-of-product-of-matrix

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I see a discussion on submultiplicativity. I would for sure answer my questions if I had pushed the norm inside the sum. Yet, the norm is of the total sum of the second matrix.